# Electric field effect on reactions

Tags: physical-chemistry, solutions, polarity

What would be the effect of putting a solution in a strong electric field? Would the reactions in the solution be affected?

I'm thinking yes – lots (if not all) – chemistry is dependent on charge (partial/real charges) and by applying an electric field, we'd be affecting the very property of the molecules/ions that drives reactions.

Has this been researched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would the reactions in the solution be affected?

Yes, they can be.  [Here](http://www.scs.illinois.edu/burke/files/group_meetings/13.10.05%20Electric%20Fields%20SGB.pdf) are some nice examples.  Electric fields also exert a significant effect on [electron transfer reactions](http://web.stanford.edu/group/boxer/papers/paper94.pdf).  Basically you would expect charged molecules to be more affected than polar molecules, which should be more affected than non-polar, but polarizable molecules.  It's just a question of how big a field you can produce and how polarized and long-lived are the various entities (starting materials, intermediates, etc.) that exist along the reaction coordinate.

Comment: is this same with magnetic field?